# how to create different instances using [(ngModel)] in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am new to angualr 4,

I am trying to create a a list and get the selected value to work with it, as I am using [(ngModel)] it applies the selected value to all the three list values , I do not want that.

```
<div *ngFor="let arr of arrName" >{{arr}}
    <input type ="text">
    <select [(ngModel)]="slecVal">
        <option *ngFor="let cl of colors" >{{cl}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

I want when I select red for first option only it's value will be updated not the other two. 
How to fix it ? and how scope works for angular 4 ??

Comment: Can you post the typescript you are using to get the array your using

Comment: @yepMe: did any of the answers below work for you?

Answer (score 2):

One option might be to change the slecVal into a map and bind each select's value to a slecVal key. For instance:

.ts

```
this.slecVal = {};
```

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let arr of arrName; let i = index;">{{arr}}
    <input type ="text">
    <select [(ngModel)]="slecVal[i]">
        <option *ngFor="let cl of colors" >{{cl}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

It may, however, be more helpful to provide the keys with a more intuitive naming convention than the index. If the value of `arr` is a meaningful string, then it's probably a better choice than `i`.

Comment: This is a nice answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use one way binding, something like:

```
<select name="select{{arr}}" [ngModel]="slecVal">
    <option *ngFor="let cl of colors" >{{cl}}</option>
</select>
```

Then can use the `ngForm` directive to obtain the selected values in the form, see the example code [**HERE**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nqkkik?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: No , I want to obtain the selected value on change only and not on submit

Comment: @yepMe: the other answer is nice one then

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrName = [ { 'name' : "valueofname" , "selectedVal":"Defaultselectoption" }] //List of objects

<div *ngFor="let arr of arrName" >{{arr.name}}
    <input type ="text">
    <select [(ngModel)]="arr.selectedVal">
        <option *ngFor="let cl of colors" >{{cl}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This way you will have the selected Value of options associated with the object.